# What is this dialog box for?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

This dialog box has been popping up every 15 minutes on my system since I set up my Gmail account in Outlook.

[image: Strange dialog box]

What is it and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to happen when you have enabled Google syncing without having a default profile set in Outlook. Every time the Google syncing runs it will pop that dialog and ask you to choose which profile you want to use for the syncing. To get rid of the popup you need to [set a default profile in Outlook](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/switch-to-another-outlook-e-mail-profile-HP001230478.aspx#BM1).

Comment: The box still shows up.

Comment: Have you rebooted?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Control Panel>Mail>Show Profiles and check "Always use this profile" and pick one. Your GMail is trying to open Outlook for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the link for information on Outlook profiles and see the section on Configure Outlook to always start with a specific profile. I hope this helps

> [outlook-e-mail-profiles-explained](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/outlook-e-mail-profiles-explained-HA001147158.aspx)